# Import sales_flat_order table from one db to another db

Tags: database, sales-order

Is it possible to import the data of sales_flat_order table to existing database from another database. Can anyone kindly guide me. Thanks in adv.

PS: By mistake I deleted all my orders at the back end. I require all the orders back. It is present in another db. However do I have to replace the entire db or just the sales_flat_order table alone can be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

You should not attempt to do this via a direct database transfer. If you want to import/export orders you should look at a way to do this programmatically as you will run into issues in the database.

I would recommend this extension to accomplish what you are trying to do

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/dataflow-batch-import-export-orders-to-csv-xml.html

Comment: Thank u for the suggestion!